# Как сохранить из видео каждый 15 кадр как фото в папку на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть видео, нужно из него сохранить каждый 15 кадр, предварительно, обрезать по векторам Xmin=115,Ymin=210, Xmax=350, Ymax=445, сделать рисайз 116*116  и сохранить каждое такое фото в папку.

Я написала код, он вроде исполнен. Но результата нет.

Видео по ссылке https://disk.yandex.ru/i/9AuLkzsd55083w

Вот мой код:

```
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Video/camera.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()

fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
est_video_length_minutes = 10.28         # Round up if not sure.
est_tot_frames = est_video_length_minutes * fps  # Sets an upper bound # of frames in video clip

n = 15                             # Desired interval of frames to include
desired_frames = n * np.arange(est_tot_frames) 

for i in desired_frames:
    vidcap.set(1,i-1)                      
    success,image = vidcap.read(1)         # image is an array of array of [R,G,B] values
    frameId = vidcap.get(1)                # The 0th frame is often a throw-away
    frameId = frameId.crop((115,210,350,445))
    frameId.resize((116, 116), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    cv2.imwrite("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Video/frame%d.jpg" % frameId, image)
    
vidcap.release()
```

Comment: Что значит нет результата?

Comment: В папке на гугл диске, в назначенной для сохранения директории, нет фото.  Вот так записывала сохранение - cv2.imwrite("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Video/frame%d.jpg" % frameId, image). Или я что-то не дописала в коде для сохранения?

Comment: Попробуйте от имени администратора запустить скрипт, и ещё попробуйте сохранить на обычный диск.

Comment: У вас в скрипте обрабатываются каким либо образом исключения?

Comment: Нет, не обрабатываются исключения. Вот весь код показала, кроме импорта библиотек и подключения к диску: from google.colab import drive                drive.mount('/content/drive')

Comment: Скрипт сколько времени работает?

Comment: Вот вывод времени - 5.51 µs ± 1.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each). На обычный диск тож хотела сохранить, не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте явно указать создание папки на гуглдиске

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive/')

path = Path("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Video")
path.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True) 
assert path.exists()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую и отпишусь!

Comment: Чего-то не получается. возможно я не правильно поняла про явное указание папки.  Если не затруднит посмотреть, Вот ссылка на тетрадку - https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I2LspdVbH5_g1bKU6IY7l0TvQnt2INZD?usp=sharing

Comment: И ещё можно спросить, говорите код сработал, прям 15 фото появились в папке?

Comment: Странно, у вас в коде не полностью выделяется ссылка на папку на гугл-колаб. Попробуйте изменить путь и создать новую папку. И еще поправьте fps. Вот ссылка на мою тетрадку -гляньте. [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1B4nkWWPyYKtl3ZDpnmNOjh5Ta5pAgCej)

Comment: Спасибо за тетрадку, поработаю со своим кодом.

Comment: А вам потом, наверное, еще надо будет нейронную сеть обучить?

Comment: ну да, сначала разделить фото, сформировать таргет и учить.

Answer (score -1):

Проверьте корректность в имени файла "camera.mp4" - важен даже регистр. У вас файл именно так называется? А не Camera.mp4, например?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Добрый вечер. Именно так называется, проверила.

Comment: У меня просто этот код не работал, пока не поправил ошибку в имени файла - после все заработало. А вот такое после drive.mount('/content/drive')  у вас есть: path = Path("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Video")
path.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True) 
assert path.exists() ?

Comment: нету такой строки. интересно. Надо попробовать с именем файла.